# ajaxurl usage for a custom function

Tags: php, functions, ajax

I am creating a custom form in one of my paste and its getting submitted using AJAX post method. Here is my code:

HTML for button :

```
<button onclick="result()" type="button" name="result_submit" id="result_submit" >Submit</button>
```

Jquery:

```
function result(){

        $.ajax({
            url  :ajaxurl,
            type :'POST',
            action :'expense_check',
            success: function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
        });             
}
```

To use ajaxurl I added below php code in head section :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

And then added below codes to my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_expense', 'expense_check' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_expense', 'expense_check' );


function expense_check(){
include_once 'dbConnection.php';

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

$income = "select SUM(amount) as incomeNumber FROM wp_formdata WHERE entry_type='Income'";
$response = '';

if (! mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$income)) {
     $response = '<h1 style="color:red;padding-top:5%;">SQL Error !!</h1>';
} else {
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     $income_sum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
     $response = "Total Income is ".$income_sum['incomeNumber'];
}

echo $response;
}
```

But its not working. I am getting below error in console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Use the `data` property to set the action name, and use the correct action name. I.e. `data: { action: 'expense' }` and not `action: 'expense_check'`. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details about the `data`.

Comment: @SallyCJ: thanks its working in chrome and IE, but FF still shows the same error. tried clearing the cookies and history, but no luck

Comment: Inspect the XHR/AJAX *request* and see if FF is sending the proper action name, and to the proper URL.

Comment: @SallyCJ: I dont see any response status and see a certificate error. It looks like issue with site certificate not with the code. thanks for your help

Comment: No problem friend. But, are you making the AJAX request from a secured/`https` page/URL? If not, that might be the issue.

Comment: yes. my original site has a secure connection. I am currently developing the page on locally installed site which uses http.

Comment: You should make the AJAX request from the *same protocol* as the `ajaxurl`'s. So try hard-coding that to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, which should work well regardless of the origin's protocol. Or when defining the `ajaxurl`, omit the protocol: `<?php echo str_replace( array('http:', 'https:'), '', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ); ?>`